# How to find roots of this equation?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, roots, problem-solving

I have this equation and want to find its roots.

$\left(a^2+1\right) \cosh (a (c -b))- \cosh (c a)=0 $.

Any comment is welcome.

Comment: Is $a$ the variable and $b$ a parameter or the inverse ?

Comment: If $b = \pi$, the equation becomes $Ca^4 - 2C a^2 + C = 0$ with $C = 1 - \cosh 2 \pi a \neq 0$ for $a > 0$. The equation $a^4 - 2a^2 + 1 = 0$, $a > 0$, only has one (double) root at $a = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has
\begin{equation}
1 \le f(a) = \frac{(a^2-1)^2}{(a^2+1)^2}\cosh(2\pi a) + \frac{4 a^2}{(a^2+1)^2}< \cosh(2\pi a)
\end{equation}
because this expression is a convex combination of $\cosh(2\pi a)$ and $1$.
Then the equation implies
\begin{equation}
b = \pi \pm \frac{1}{2a}\cosh^{-1}(f(a))\in (0, 2\pi)
\end{equation}
Hence for every $a$ there are two solutions $b$, except in the case where $f(a)=1$ which happens only when $a=1$. In this case there is only one solution $b = \pi$.

Plotting $b$ as a function of $a$ (with the $+$ sign) indicates that $b$ decreases from $2\pi$ to $\pi$ when $a$ varies from $0$ to $1$ and increases from $\pi$ to $2\pi$ when $a$ varies from $1$ to $+\infty$, so there should be two solutions $a$ for each $b\in (\pi, 2\pi)$, one of them in $(0, 1)$ and the other one in $(1, +\infty)$. The condition $a<10$ is irrelevant and should be removed.

[image]

Comment: Note that the above curve is not a proof, although it is a very strong reason to believe the result.

Comment: I proved that there are two $b$ for each $a$. What I haven't proved is that $b$ decreases and then increases as I see it on  the graph. If you can prove this monotonicity, it would make a whole proof that there are two $a$ for each $b$.

Comment: There may be other ways to prove that there are two solutions $a$ for each $b$, but I don't know them. If you want to follow the above method, it is necessary to prove the monotonicity. One could start by computing the derivative of $b$ for example. Monotonicity is a very powerful argument in the study of equations.

Comment: No because the $-$ sign gives $b\in (0, \pi)$ and the $+$ sign gives $b\in (\pi, 2\pi)$. There is a symmetrical curve with respect to the horizontal line $b=\pi$ on the graph.